# bootstrap.widgets.tbgridview add classname same as value

Tags: yii

I want to add  class name so class name will be same as row value data

```
     $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
        'id'=>'testcaseResult-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
            'filter'=>$model,
            'rowCssClassExpression'=>'"items[]_{$data->result_id}"',

        'columns'=>array(
          ....
            array(
                'name'=>'result_text',
                'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:300px;text-align:center;'),
                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'result_text'),
            ),
            array(
                'name'=>'result_severnity',
                'value'=> '$data->getResultSevernity()',
                'filter'=>$resultSevernityList,
                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>$data->getResultSevernity()),
                'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:300px;text-align:center;'),
....
```

1. In first field '**result_text**' is  field name in table. Which
   gives its value      and I want classname as same value. But not
   'result_text'.
2. I have **result_severnity** which have different numerical value. I
   have created fubction in model to get specific string value
       for it. And I want same class name for it.

> 'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>$data->getResultSevernity()),

My question is for **No.2 To have same value for class name** as it shown in row data, which is not working.

Thanks in advance for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got answer from my Guru. 
Instead of giving class name to self element adding a span tag with class name is great trick.

- setting returned value with span tag
- adding type => 'raw'
- passing a parameter for  adding span tag

> 'value'=> '$data->getResultSevernity('HTML')',

```
........     
array(
            'name'=>'result_severnity',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value'=> '$data->getResultSevernity()',
            'filter'=>$resultSevernityList,
            'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:300px;text-align:center;'),
....

model:
    public function getResultSevernity($type="")
        {
            $resultSevernity = $this->result_severnity;
            switch($resultSevernity)
            {
                case '0':
                    $returnText = t("common","severnity_none");
                    break;
                case '10':
                    $returnText = t("common","severnity_minor");
                    break;
                    ......
                }
            if($type=="HTML") {
                $class = "severnity_".$resultSevernity;
                $returnText = cHtmlTag($returnText, 'span', array('class'=>$class));
            }
            return $returnText;
        }
```